# Best way to ask user to select either image or color

Tags: user-centered-design, select

What is the best way to ask user to select either image or color. I made one is it the correct UX

[image]

**UPDATE**

Users can select multiple images or a single color

**UPDATE**

Actually from this interface I am giving user 3 options users can choose ONLY ONE OPTION.

1. Users can select a single color to set as their dashboard background.
2. Users can select a single image to set as their dashboard background image
3. Users can select multiple images to set as ther dashboard background image ( this option will auto change image in every 30second)

And I want to know best way to present this to user

Comment: Don't understand your question. What's the use case?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you're trying to create a color palette by asking the users to select the colors manually or choose them automatically from a photo right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the user is supposed to choose **one** item, the interface should probably reflect this already by offering **one** collection of items. Currently you have *two collections* (colors and images) which forces the user to make at least two decisions:

1. Color **or** Image
2. Which color / Which Image

If possible I would recommend to drop the naming of the different collections, throw everything in one box instead and adjust the wording accordingly e.g. like "Select a mood" or "Select a theme" or the like. This way you could also add color combinations, radients or whatever suits your use case best.

[image]

Comment: But issue is, Users can select multiple images or a single color

Comment: @miqdad -- WHAT?! What is the user trying to accomplish? I feel like you are optimizing the wrong thing. There is something weird in your application if the user ever has to make a choice between two dissimilar sets with dissimilar conditions. I would suggest you consider refactoring your workflow instead of trying to do anything other than tillinberlin's idea.

Comment: updated in question

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd be better off showing 2 icons along with the text Color or Image. Perhaps a little icon with some color swatches and your typical image icon you see in most wysiwig editors?

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean here? As it currently reads it just sounds like you're suggesting the same approach the OP has already provided in the question.

Comment: Sure .. Yeah it really is, but just simplifying it. If it's a case of choosing either/or, which is what Miqdad suggested. Simplify their choice by showing icons/text vs big blocks of colors/images and text. This should reduce the cognitive effort and time it takes them to make a choice.